# Different line thickness between Painter 12 and Painter 2015

Tags: drawing-tablet

I am migrating from Painter 12 to Painter 2015 and use the Wacom Intuos M tablet. Now, I've set the same line width settings in 2015 as I have in 12 but I get an extremely thin line when drawing with the pen (and identical lines when using the mouse).

Clearly I've missed a setting somewhere, can someone help me out figuring what and where it is? Here's a screenshot:

[image]